# Amazon Lex display response/message before Lambda Fulfilment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I have a basic chat bot using Amazon Lex that asks the users some questions which then takes those answers and sends them to the fulfilment Lambda function to process it. 
Before the Lambda function is triggered, I would like to display a message to the chat window stating the request is being processed as it could take up to a minute to process the request. 
I would like to display a message such as "Thank you, your request is being processed" instead of waiting up to a minute for a response from the Lambda function.

Is this something that is possible via Lex?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have a look to this question ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55706446/play-a-message-to-the-user-after-confirmation-prompt-like-please-wait-while-w

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame. Guess I'll do that. Thanks @JaimeS